# Why do CausesValidation does not propagate from Containers to child controls?

Tags: c#, winforms, validation

I am using c#.

Why does the CausesValidation property does not propagate from containers to child controls?

I have a TabControl and i need to perform validation of user input on all tabs.
But each tab is independent. I found out that if i have a container like a TableLayoutPanel and i set CausesValidation to false, the child componentes still perform validation.

So this code would not work:

```
Foreach(Control c in Container.Controls)
{
    c.CausesValidation = False;
}
```

If you do some DEBUG output you will see that the only found control is the TableLayoutPanel or any other container like a GroupBox that will be found and set to False. But containers are not propagating that value to the child level.
A lot of people asked how we could solve the problem. I found a lot of methods, but i have created a static class that allows me to select wich tab on the TabControl that i want to perform validation, and it will set CausesValidation to False on ALL controls of that TabControl, including child controls with a deepness of 10 layers. If you want that library just ask for it!

My real question is, should not a container propagate that property to its child controls, and that child controls to any child controls?!

It would save us a lot of work from creating a very crazy code that is very specific for something that should work from scratch? Why is this not implied?

Answer (score 2):

This just isn't a constructive way to deal with your requirement.  The feature just wasn't implemented the way you like it to work and that's never going to change.  It isn't a problem, you can easily add it yourself with a wee bit of code:

```
    public static void SetCausesValidation(Control.ControlCollection ctls, bool enable) {
        foreach (Control ctl in ctls) {
            ctl.CausesValidation = enable;
            SetCausesValidation(ctl.Controls, enable);
        }
    }
```

And use it in your form constructor, something like:

```
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        SetCausesValidation(panel1.Controls, false);
    }
```

Note the use of recursion in the method to set the property through the entire tree of controls inside the container.