# Cannot access all controls on form using foreach loop

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to introduce color themes in my C# application just like it is in visual studio

- Blue
- Dark
- Light

There are multiple panel on the form and each panel has multiple controls in it like (groupbox, label, textboxes, panels). Now consider the code below:

```
  foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls)
  {
    if (ctrl is Panel)
    {
      (ctrl as Panel).BackColor = Color.FromArgb(214, 219, 233);
    }
    if (ctrl is GroupBox)
    {
      (ctrl as GroupBox).BackColor = Color.FromArgb(214, 219, 233);
    }
  }
```

Problem is

```
if(ctrl is Panel){ (ctrl as Panel).BackColor = Color.FromArgb(214, 219, 233); }
```

changes the **backcolor** of the main panels on the form but it doesnot change the *color* of **panels** inside that panel and other controls also.

Comment: Controls on a form have a tree structure.  Visiting a tree is always best done with [recursive code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19272592/17034).

Answer (score 1):

`this.Controls` only returns direct children of control (`Form` in this case), so children of these children are not returned. To go through all controls on the `Form`, you can either use recursion like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetBackColorRecursively(this);
}

private void SetBackColorRecursively(Control ctrl)
{
    if (ctrl is Panel)
    {
        (ctrl as Panel).BackColor = Color.FromArgb(214, 219, 233);
    }
    if (ctrl is GroupBox)
    {
        (ctrl as GroupBox).BackColor = Color.FromArgb(214, 219, 233);
    }

    // Recursively set BackColor on all children
    foreach (Control c in ctrl.Controls)
    {
        SetBackColorRecursively(c);
    }
}
```

or you can create `Flatten` method, that will enumerate all controls, including grand-children:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Control ctrl in Flatten(this))
    {
        if (ctrl is Panel)
        {
            (ctrl as Panel).BackColor = Color.FromArgb(214, 219, 233);
        }
        if (ctrl is GroupBox)
        {
            (ctrl as GroupBox).BackColor = Color.FromArgb(214, 219, 233);
        }
    }
}

static IEnumerable<Control> Flatten(Control c)
{
    yield return c;

    foreach (Control o in c.Controls)
    {
        foreach (var oo in Flatten(o))
            yield return oo;
    }
}
```